# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from tab crashed in Python with Odoo, But selenium working fine alone ,

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, odoo

I am using the selenium integrating with odoo 13
executing the code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dev/chromedriver')
```

from odoo. I think there is some conflict with odoo session.
But when I execute this code form a separate python file, it works well. I also tried to execute this code using Django application  on a button click . It works well and browser will open. But in odoo project it won't work. I am really confused why it is not working.

```
Odoo Server Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
        raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
        result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 909, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1323, in call_button
        action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1311, in _call_kw
        return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/api.py", line 395, in call_kw
        result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/odoo/api.py", line 382, in _call_kw_multi
        result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/odoo-13.0/custom_modules_13/testing/models/models.py", line 28, in send_whatsapp_message
        driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
        self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 250, in start_session
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 323, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "/home/dev/odoo13_home/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 240, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
    from tab crashed
      (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
    Stacktrace:
    #0 0x560acf67fd29 <unknown>
```

Comment: What's your chrome version and your driver version?

Comment: The version of driver is : ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) and browser version is: Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: They are closing the Question, But the solution does not works.

Comment: @SatyaDevYadav did you get any solution for this. i had similar issue with Odoo14, Google chrome / driver 89.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

Your chrome version is `80.0.3987.132`,Try to download [this Chrome webdriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/),Add your webdriver folder to system PATH,and try again.

Comment: same problem, the browser pops-up and close at once.

Comment: So did you add the folder to your system PATH?After you add it to your PATH,you needn't to use `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dev/chromedriver')` in your code.

Comment: same problem, It is not working...

Comment: @SatyaDevYadav Maybe you can try to change the version of Chrome and webdriver.Use the old version.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, How to get the old version of Chrome?

Comment: @SatyaDevYadav It is a little complicated,You can just Google it.

Comment: hay man it is not working

Comment: @SatyaDevYadav Maybe you can try to ask a new one,post more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209758/discussion-between-satya-dev-yadav-and-jizhihaosama).